# Semantic UI checkbox icon won't load

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

I am using Semantic UI 2.4.0 as front end framework for my project. CSS file is loading correctly on the page.

**html**

```
        <div class="inline field">
            <label>Status</label>
            <div class="ui checked checkbox">
                <input type="hidden" value="0" name="isActive">
                <input type="checkbox" checked="" name="isActive" value="1">
                <label>Active</label>
            </div>
            <div class="ui checked checkbox">
                <input type="hidden" value="0" name="isDiscontinued">
                <input type="checkbox" name="isDiscontinued" value='1'>
                <label>Discontinued</label>
            </div>
            <?php echo form_error('status'); ?>
        </div>
```

Everything else works fine. Somehow, the check icon of the checkbox won't load,like below:

[image]

Styles shows in dev tool look like below:

```
.ui.checkbox .box:after, .ui.checkbox label:after {
    content: '\e801';
}
```

I tried to change content to '\f00c', which is the unicode for icon check in the latest font awesome, it won't load either. Please help, thanks!

Comment: Post the HTML too please.

Comment: Have you tried a different browser? And please, post the code as text not as an image in the future. Preferably, not from the page inspector but from your code.

Comment: This might be a dumb question, but just checking: Are you including semantic ui's css file? is it loading correctly into the document?

Comment: CSS file is loading correctly..

Comment: I used the exact same code as you and it worked just fine. Double check that your Sematinc library is not corrupt, download a new one and try using a different browser. Be sure that you have the correct paths used.

Comment: If you're sure the codes are right, the font probably isn't loading, but you should notice this since all other icons shouldn't be empty squares like that too.
Post some more code

Comment: Please mark my answer as the solution if it worked. glad to be of help. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.ui.checkbox .box:after, .ui.checkbox label:after {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: '\e801';
}
```

Comment: Sementic UI won't let me over write it.

Comment: Glad it helped :) please accept the answer with the green V. thank you

Comment: I am sorry, I would love to accept your answer. but it did not actually work in my case.